# mysql left join binary group by

Tags: mysql, binary, group-by, left-join

I have three tables, tag is a column present in two of them (in the second table the same tag is present on multiple rows), they are both set to Varchar(70) and indexed as Full Text. the_id is a column in the first table (it's not the primary id but is indexed as Index).

So my question is, why would this query take between 4 to 8 seconds to respond:

> SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_3 ON (table_1.the_id = table_3.id) LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.tag = table_2.tag WHERE table_2.bad = 0 GROUP BY table_1.the_id

(I use this query to make sure that there is at least 1 row that is not set as bad in the second table and I group by the_id to not show duplicate entries with similar tags but the same the_id, which I use to join the third table by it's primary id)

Explained Query:

```
id  |  select_type  |  table   |  type  |  possible_keys  |  key  |  key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  Extra
1   |     simple    | table_1  |  ALL   |      tag        | NULL  |   NULL    | NULL  |  2809  | Using temporary; Using filesort
1   |     simple    | table_2  |  ALL   |    bad,tag      | NULL  |   NULL    | NULL  |  3689  | Using where
1   |     simple    | table_3  | eq_ref |    PRIMARY      |PRIMARY|     8     |the_id |    1   |
```

Comment: Post explain plan of your whole query `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_1 ...`

Comment: I added the mysql query explain result

Comment: Your explain plan uses index for `bad,tag` but you have not indexed your tag column for your table1 so add index for table1's tag column too also don't select * select only needed columns

Comment: This is a simplified version of the actual query, I am ofcourse selecting only the needed columns in the actual query. I added a version of the query that is closer to what I actually use, including the third table, although that shouldn't be the problem because it uses the primary key to join. But tag is indexed as Full Text in both tables, could it be that it doesn't use the index because I call BINARY from the ON statement?

Comment: yes remove binary in your on clause and see if it uses the index for table1

Comment: I've removed binary from the on clause and edited the topic again, now it uses the tag index, but still takes more then 4 seconds to load

Comment: I've managed to fix it, the problem was that mysql did not accept binary search in the on clause, so the query didn't use the fulltext index, after removing binary from the on clause and adding a normal index on tag, it started using the new index, thanks Khalid, you saved me 4 mins of waiting time on every page load :)